# Does The Famo.us web platform support phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, cordova, famo.us

I would like to integrate notifications and bluetooth via phonegap to my web app built with famo.us. Is it possible?

Comment: Try a google search for this. This site is for programming specific questions and code debugging help.

Comment: We do not know yet, because famo.us is not yet released. Besides, famo.us is planning to release its own phonegap: http://vimeo.com/86727807 So I would conclude that it is very well possible.

Comment: They're working on their own phonegap wrapper. http://www.infoworld.com/t/mobile-development/famous-were-building-better-phonegap-236267

Answer (score 6):

`Famo.us` includes the `Famo.us Toolbar` which itself is a mod of Cordova (similar to Phonegap) and includes all of the plugins Cordova supports. It's driven from the command line.

I've emailed the CEO of `Famo.us` and his response was:

> We are alpha testing the Famo.us Wrapper now.  It's a mod of Cordova
>   with all of the plugins from Cordova.  The difference is that it's
>   much more performant, especially on Android, than PhoneGap or Cordova.

Comment: Yes, and their wrapper is more performant because they package the latest chrome/blink engine in the app. If you read their FAQ, you'll see that with each version of chrome, the FPS goes significantly up

Comment: It's important to note, that there is almost no difference in performance as iOS always uses it's own webView, and so there is no difference in performace.

Answer (score 6):

To achieve better performance than the standard Android webview, you could try to wrap your application with the Crosswalk runtime, it works with famo.us:

- download the Crosswalk archive, e.g. https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/stable/5.34.104.5/crosswalk-5.34.104.5.zip
- unpack the downloaded archive
- from the unpacked crosswalk folder, run ./make_apk.py --name="Your App" --package="com.example.app" --app-root=/your/app/root/folder --app-local-path=index.html

This will produce an .apk that you can install to the device.

More information: https://crosswalk-project.org

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

Famo.us DOES support phoneGap. It's just HTML, CSS and javascript so it can be wrapped like anything else. The main difference is that PhoneGap and Cordova use an old version of Chromium which gives it bad performance on Android, which is why Famo.us's own wrapper will be more performant.

Specially on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Right now The Famous Toolbelt has not been released publicly (only to a small subset of testers) but if you've used the [**Yeoman Generator**](https://github.com/Famous/generator-famous) you can quite easily wrap the compiled code into a normal Phonegap project. The only thing you should avoid doing is directly manipulating the DOM (i.e not using Famous to modify the layout & contents)

The rest is the same as writing any other Cordova app from a Javascript perspective. Just make sure to include and initialise Cordova and your plugins correctly beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested `famo.us` with `phonegap` and it works. However the performance when starting up is terrible. Some reason `phonegap` takes a long time to load. But after that it works just fine. Basically these are the steps:

**1. Install phonegap**

**2. Create the project**

`# phonegap create helloworld`

`# cd helloworld`

**3. Build the project**

Then copy the `famo.us` project folder into `www` folder

`# phonegap build ios`

(or android)